# Is it posible to use markup inheritance with apache wicket panels

Tags: java, inheritance, wicket, markup

I am trying to implements a wicket panel which inherits from a parent panel.  I have used the same patterns as used for inheritance in pages.  Hence for panels.

**Parent panel markup  **

```
<wicket:panel>    
<parent markup>  
<wicket:child/>  
</wicket:panel>
```

**Child panel **

```
<wicket:extend>
  child markup here.
</wicket:extend>
```

However the child markup is not shown and I receive no errors.

Anybody have any ideass?

Answer (score 1):

Markup inheritance is not restricted to pages, it can be used for all components with their own markup.

From your code I cannot see why it isn't working for you.